# How to pass in an ArrayList of strings and convert each separate array into it's own string (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, infinite-loop

So i'm taking an input file containing strings like:

```
birthday54
happy75
nifty43
bob1994
```

These strings are part of an ArrayList. I want to pass this ArrayList through a method that can take each individual string and print them out individually. So basically, how do i take an ArrayList of strings, separate each individual string, and then print those strings? In my code, my while loop condition is true so i have an infinite loop going here and it's only outputting the first string "birthday54" infinitely. I don't know what condition i should have for the while loop. Or if i should even have a while loop. Here is my code:

```
    public static void convArrListToString(ArrayList<String> strings){
            int i=0;
            while (true){
                 String[] convert = strings.toArray(new String[i]);  
                 System.out.println(convert[i]);
                }  
            }
    public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("myinputcases.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (in.hasNext())
        list.add(in.next());

    convArrListToString(list);
```

Comment: What you're doing is just crazy...

Comment: lol i know. my main purpose of redundantly converting this arraylist into strings is so i can use the strings to convert them into their ascii equivalent, but i've already figured that part out.

Comment: *how do i take an ArrayList of strings, separate each individual string...* An list of strings is already separated. It's not clear what you're trying to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
while (true) {
    String[] convert = strings.toArray(new String[i]);  
    System.out.println(convert[i]);
}
```

To this:

```
for (String strTemp : strings) {
    System.out.println(strTemp);
}
```

It only ouputs "**birthday54**" because you didn't increment your `i`. You can increment it by putting `i++` on the end of your while statement, but you will get an error if you do that after you iterate all of your values in your `ArrayList`. Look my answer, you can simply use `for` loop to iterate that `ArrayList`.

Comment: Surely you mean `strings.forEach(System.out::println);`.

Comment: @shmosel yeah, that's absolutely short than my answer. thanks :)

Comment: hey @shmosel, how can i take those strings that i just printed (using your code) and pass them through another different function?

Comment: @user7428413 If it's a static method, you can do `strings.forEach(ClassName::methodName);`

Comment: this is awesome, I learn new things too. thanks for that @shmosel.

Comment: @shmosel, you are an absolute genius. one more question, if i implement that code you just wrote and pass it in a function that utilizes a for loop, is the run time O(n^2) or O(n)?

Comment: Depends what the for loop is. Say it's looping over characters in each string, it would be O(n*m), where m is the number of chars.

Comment: if i wanted a counter to count how many times this foreach loop iterates, how would i go about setting that up?

Comment: @user7428413 if you want to know how many loop it will iterate, just use the `strings.size()` to know the length of your `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you only need to iterate the ArrayList and use the "Get" method to get each string like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++){ 
   System.out.println(list.get(i)); 
}
```

or you can use the for each loop

```
for(String s : list){ 
 System.out.println(s);
}
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Man that's painful to look at, Try this instead of your while loop:

```
for (String s : strings) { 
     System.out.println(s); 
}
```

No while loop needed, the array list is a Collections object which is a container class in Java that can be iterated by object as well as by index, so this should pull each string out 1 by 1 until it approaches the end of the array list.

[Resource on collections in java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).